# Use css to ensure only one block is shown

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

```
{this.state.company && <p class="abc">abc</p>}
{this.state.company2 && <p class="abc">abc</p>}
```

I have 2 tag in my template engine, sometime one will appear sometime both will appear, but for user he should  always see one. How can I use css to display only one item?

if I do

```
p:last-child {
   display:none
}
```

but when the result is only one present, that will not work.

Comment: css `display:none`

Comment: :nth-child to hide the one you want

Comment: Would you want to change the visibility on the fly also (once the page is loaded as this might involve javascript) or it is a one time exercise only while loading the page?

Comment: @kevin are u sure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only hide them, if they are not the first child:

```
p:not(:first-child) {
   display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If there's only 2 blocks, then:

```
p:nth-child(2) {
   display:none;
}
```

The second child (if any) is always gonna be the last one!

Comment: can't it be p:not(:first-child) ?

Comment: Yes, it can, but mine is also another solution. If mine really works for you, too, please consider giving it an up-vote. Thanks ^^ !

Answer (score 0):

Make the inversed solution. Tag them as `hidden` and show always the first with a css selector.